# Nearest marker to designated zip or address Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a database of approximately 500 addresses with geocoded coordinates. The way things are set up now is that all 500 addresses are marked on the map using the default markers, now what I need to do is to be able to type in an address or zip code and find out which of the 500 addresses in my database are the nearest to the address or zip code typed in. Is there a built in function for this in the Google Maps API? I am curious how I would accomplish this I have been searching for a way and not coming up with any results.

Comment: Like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_closestMarker_geocode.html)?

Comment: Similar but I would also like to have miles included. I found that the distance matrix that google offers only allows a certain number of requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provides the `computeDistanceBetween` function to calculate the straight-line distance between two `google.maps.LatLng` points.

Modify your script tag to include the optional geometry library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Then call the `computeDistanceBetween`  as such:

```
var distanceInMeters = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(origin, dest);
```

Dev docs @ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance

If you want to calculate the actual travel distance/time, you need to use the Google Distance Matrix API.  (As @Yamaha32088 mentions, the Distance Matrix API has very strict quota limits which you may quickly exceed depending on your license.)

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/ for more info on the distance matrix API.